# Angular 2+ - Set base href dynamically

Tags: angular

We have an enterprise app that uses Angular 2 for the client. Each of our customers has their own unique url, ex: `https://our.app.com/customer-one` and `https://our.app.com/customer-two`. Currently we are able to set the `<base href...>` dynamically using `document.location`. So user hits `https://our.app.com/customer-two` and `<base href...>` gets set to `/customer-two`...perfect!

The problem is if the user is for example at `https://our.app.com/customer-two/another-page` and they refresh the page or try to hit that url directly, the `<base href...>` gets set to `/customer-two/another-page` and the resources can't be found.

We've tried the following to no avail:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var base = document.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    document.write('<base href="/' + base + '" />');
  </script>

...
```

Unfortunately we are fresh out of ideas. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Have you attempted anything with [APP_BASE_HREF](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html)? I am not quite sure how it would be implemented, but it seems to be something that would be useful...

Comment: Of course it definitely depends on which version of the router you are currently using as well. Are you on the router version 3.0.0-alpha.x?

Comment: I'm using "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7"

Comment: Hmmm.... I have been trying to understand the router and the best practices as well... Perhaps you should not set the base href dynamically and instead use [children routes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)?

Comment: I would like to do the same thing. Anymore ideas ?

Comment: Angular 7 - November 2018. this is still an issue. current answers provide a partial solution. doing stuff inside angular module is too late. as your index HTML is served it needs to know where to pull the scripts from. there are only 2 ways the way I see it - using asp\php\whatever to serve index.html with dynamic basehref content. or using native javascript right on the index.html file to change DOM content before it gets to angular. both are poor solutions to a common problem. sad.

Comment: Can someone please answer my query also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757931/angular-5-dynamic-base-reference-is-causing-duplicate-loading-of-bundleschunk

Comment: I ran into this same problem and specially using `@angular/pwa`, my approach was to make the server "Virtualize" ng app distribution, I detect the base URL for the customer and that it's requiring an angular App, then while responding `index.html` or `ngsw.json` I replace their content with the backend. It's fugly as shit, but it works.

Comment: Angular 12 - September 2021, any new solutions with the latest angular version?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's what we ended up doing.

Add this to index.html. It should be the first thing in the `<head>` section

```
<base href="/">
<script>
  (function() {
    window['_app_base'] = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  })();
</script>
```

Then in the `app.module.ts` file, add `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/' }` to the list of providers, like so:

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';


import { AppComponent, routing, appRoutingProviders, environment } from './';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/' },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature. `useValue: (window as any) ['_app_base'] || '/'`helps

Comment: Does not really work for the latest ng2, is there a solution? (loads bad scripts path, then good scripts path, but not on mobile)

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to further refactor it a little, so that we don't have to hack out a function in `index.html`.

Comment: Adding it as an answer below, as the content length is too long for a comment.

Comment: @Amit Please see my answer below for an easy solve in the newest ng2.

Comment: How did you solve issue with other files. My browser is trying to load http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js, but it can't because my contextPath is different? (It should be fetching http://localhost:8080/hello/main.bundle.js.)

Comment: Can you please help me in answering my qstn also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757931/angular-5-dynamic-base-reference-is-causing-duplicate-loading-of-bundleschunk

Comment: This works in angular 10. But make sure to remove <base href="/"> line from index.html and remove setting base href in angular.json file.

Answer (score 215):

The marked answer here did not solve my issue, possibly different angular versions. I was able to achieve the desired outcome with the following `angular cli` command in terminal / shell:

`ng build --base-href /myUrl/`

`ng build --bh /myUrl/` or `ng build --prod --bh /myUrl/`

This changes the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/myUrl/">` in the **built version only** which was perfect for our change in environment between development and production. The best part was no code base requires changing using this method.

---

To summarise, leave your `index.html` base href as: `<base href="/">` then run `ng build --bh ./` with angular cli to make it a relative path, or replace the `./` with whatever you require.

---

#### Update:

As the example above shows how to do it from command line, here is how to add it to your angular.json configuration file.

This will be used for all `ng serving` for local development

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "baseHref": "/testurl/",
```

This is the config specific for configuration builds such as prod:

```
"configurations": {
   "Prod": {
     "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "baseHref": "./productionurl/",
```

The [official](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml) `angular-cli` documentation referring to usage.

Comment: This solution requires a build per customer, which is probably not solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @MaximeMorin in my experience so far doing this, `./` works for all locations. So actually I don't think you have to build per client.

Comment: @Zze My experience with `./` has been very different.  It works until the user navigates to a route and hit the browser's refresh button or keys.  At that point, our rewrites handle the call, serves the index page, but the browser assumes that `./` is the current route not the web app's root folder.  We solved the OP's issue with a dynamic (.aspx, .php, .jsp, etc) index which sets the base href.

Comment: Using `--prod` during the build will not change your `base href` value, you shouldn't talk about it here. `--prod` tells `angular-cli` to use the `environment.prod.ts` file instead of the default file `environment.ts` in your `environments` folder

Comment: @MattewEon It was just demonstrating that it was compatible with the `--prod` flag since they were talking about deployment in the OP.

Comment: @Zze Oh okay. To my mind it's surely compatible because they do different actions, I just wanted to be sure you and other will understand the meaning of `--prod` flag

Comment: **Angular 7.1: `Unknown option: '--bh'`**. `--base-href` works.

Comment: Docs are here now if anyone is looking for more details (prob not more details yet just official...) https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: This format works on my end for Angular 16  "baseHref": "productionurl" and yes in each of the config

Answer (score 45):

Based on your (@sharpmachine) answer, I was able to further refactor it a little, so that we don't have to hack out a function in `index.html`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './';
import { getBaseLocation } from './shared/common-functions.util';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: getBaseLocation
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And, `./shared/common-functions.util.ts` contains:

```
export function getBaseLocation() {
    let paths: string[] = location.pathname.split('/').splice(1, 1);
    let basePath: string = (paths && paths[0]) || 'my-account'; // Default: my-account
    return '/' + basePath;
}
```

Comment: I have myapp deployed to subfolder.  My url now looks like this: 
`http://localhost:8080/subfolder/myapp/#/subfolder/myroute`
Is this how yours look like?  Do you know how to get rid of the subfolder after the # so that it can just be `http://localhost:8080/subfolder/myapp/#/myroute`?

Comment: Oh.  I think href base is only required for LocationStrategy.  In my case, I am using HashLocationStrategy.  So I con't even need to set it.  Did you have write special code to handle refresh with LocationStrategy?

Comment: Yes, `base href` is only required for `LocationStrategy` AFAIK. As for writing special code to handle refresh with LocationStrategy, not sure what you mean exactly. Are you asking, what if my "base href" changes during an activity in my app? Then, yes, I had to do a dirty thing like `window.location.href = '/' + newBaseHref;` where it was required to be changed. I am not too proud of it. Also, to give an update, I moved away from these hack solutions in my app as it was becoming a design problem for me. Router params work perfectly fine, so I stuck to it.

Comment: What does your `appRoutingProvider` look like, Krishnan? I see the accepted answer used the same; maybe you just copied his `providers`, but if not, can you give me a sample or describe its purpose? The [documentation only **`imports`** routing modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), it doesn't use any routing-related providers (as far as I can see)

Comment: @Krishnan Here is what I have to do with nginx to make it work:
`location /subfolder/myapp/ {
        try_files $uri /subfolder/myapp/index.html;
    }

    location /subfolder2/myapp/ {
        try_files $uri /subfolder2/myapp/index.html;
    }`

Comment: @TheRedPea yes, sorry, I just copied the accepted answer's snippet. My main purpose was only to show how to use `useFactory` option for providers to keep the code clean, that's all. I don't think any of those imports matter or are related to the context of this question. Maybe, better I edit my snippet, to avoid any confusion.

@techguy2000 sorry, I have no idea about nginx. If it worked for you then great, and good to know too!

Comment: Nice dynamic solution but I'm struggling with calling app via `http://my.app.com/app1` (no / at the end). Using hardcoded base-href and calling `http://my.app.com/app1` changes url automatically to `http://my.app.com/app1/`

Comment: @xforfun I suspect that the trailing slash is added not by the Angular app but your *web server* when it is redirecting the request to the appropriate website. Curious to know if that is the case.

Comment: This works in angular 10. But make sure to remove <base href="/"> line from index.html and remove setting base href in angular.json file.

Answer (score 25):

I use the current working directory `./` when building several apps off the same domain:

```
<base href="./">
```

On a side note, I use `.htaccess` to assist with my routing on page reload:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the `.htaccess` file

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it does not work for routes such as /your-app/a/b/c.  If you refresh your page from such a route, Angular will look for the runtime, polyfills and main JS files and styles CSS file under /your-app/a/b/.  They are obviously not at that location, but under /your-app/

Comment: @toongeorges This answer was written almost two years ago using a configuration file that is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server software to handle routing on page reload. For you to say this solution is incorrect and does not work is misleading, but what you mean is that you could not figure out how to get it to work with your configuration.

Comment: I overlooked the Apache rewrite rule and I do not know enough about it to say that this would not work on Apache, so I may be wrong and your answer may be correct.  Though in any case I prefer a solution that does not require you to modify the server configuration as there have been given multiple answers here, because this makes the application portable across different servers.

Comment: Using `./` breaks routing to addresses which are multiple levels deep. e.g. `http://localhost:4200/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 20):

Simplification of the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084260/1563840) by [@sharpmachine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4164216/sharpmachine).

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useValue: '/' + (window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] || '')
        }
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

You do not have to specify a base tag in your index.html, if you are providing value for APP_BASE_HREF opaque token.

Comment: This is very similar (and thus supported) to official documentation https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 14):

This work fine for me in prod environment

```
<base href="/" id="baseHref">
<script>
  (function() {
    document.getElementById('baseHref').href = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/";
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: This solution has a great limitation with multiple VD setup in IIS. It causes the duplicate loading of chunks.

Comment: Using hardcoded base-href and calling `http://my.app.com/app1` changes url to `http://my.app.com/app1/` ( / at the end)
This solution also worked for me fine in case of `http://my.app.com/app1` since in changes to `http://my.app.com/app1/` - otherwise resources cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 8):

In angular4, you can also configure the baseHref in .angular-cli.json apps.

in .angular-cli.json

```
{   ....
 "apps": [
        {
            "name": "myapp1"
            "baseHref" : "MY_APP_BASE_HREF_1"
         },
        {
            "name": "myapp2"
            "baseHref" : "MY_APP_BASE_HREF_2"
         },
    ],
}
```

this will update base href in index.html to MY_APP_BASE_HREF_1

```
ng build --app myapp1
```

Comment: This also needs to make a build for each app.

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar problem, actually I ended up in probing the existence of some file within my web.

**probePath** would be the relative URL to the file you want to check for (kind of a marker if you're now at the correct location), e.g. 'assets/images/thisImageAlwaysExists.png'

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function configExists(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false); 
    req.send();
    return req.status==200;
  }

  var probePath = '...(some file that must exist)...';
  var origin = document.location.origin;
  var pathSegments = document.location.pathname.split('/');

  var basePath = '/'
  var configFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < pathSegments.length; i++) {
    var segment = pathSegments[i];
    if (segment.length > 0) {
      basePath = basePath + segment + '/';
    }
    var fullPath = origin + basePath + probePath;
    configFound = configExists(fullPath);
    if (configFound) {
      break;
    }
  }

  document.write("<base href='" + (configFound ? basePath : '/') + "' />");
</script>
```

Comment: This solution was the only one really working for my deployment scenario: fully dynamic base path and PathLocationStrategy. All the other solutions would not work on hard reload on sub-paths.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Angular CLI 6, you can use the deployUrl/baseHref options in angular.json (projects > xxx > architect > build > configurations > production). In this way, you can easily specify the baseUrl per project.

Check that your settings are correct by looking at the index.html of the built app.

Comment: this requires a different build for each environment, with all its implications.

Answer (score 3):

Add-ons:If you want for eg: /users as application base for router and /public as base for assets use

```
$ ng build -prod --base-href /users --deploy-url /public
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the base href dynamically in the app.module.ts file using this: https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This does not have the same exact effect as setting `<base href="/my/app"/>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094451/what-is-the-difference-between-html-base-href-and-angular-app-base-href

Answer (score 0):

In package.json set flag --base-href to relative path:

```
"script": {
    "build": "ng build --base-href ./"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late for the show, but you can use a rewrite rule if you are deploying to IIS (I am sure it can be done with other webservers as well).

You can modify the content of the outgoing response when the index.html is requested and replace the base href dynamically. (url rewrite module must be installed into IIS)

The following example assumes you have `<base href="/angularapp/">` in your index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Modify base href to current path">
                    <match filterByTags="Base" pattern="^(.*)(/angularapp/)(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)/index.html$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:1}/" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a massive headache, #location strategy doesnt seem to do what is says on the tin (seemed like it was an obvios fix but sadly not) so here is what worked for me. Thanks to all for the pointers!

**Note** I am calling php pages from within my app that are relative to the application path, this was going wrong on a refresh because the folder was one level too high. This is addressed in the **in2** section of the config below.

Create a web.config file and put it in your /src folder

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>

<rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="in2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)(.php)" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="../{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="../myappname/" />
            </rule>

</rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Create a myappname.html file and put it in the /src folder
Add both to the Angular.json build section under assets

```
"assets":{ ["projects/myapp/src/myappname.html","projects/toolbar2/src/web.config"
]
```

In the index.html

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function configExists(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url, false); 
  req.send();
  return req.status==200;
}

var probePath = 'myappname.html';
var origin = document.location.origin;
var pathSegments = document.location.pathname.split('/');

var basePath = '/'
var configFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i < pathSegments.length; i++) {
  var segment = pathSegments[i];
  if (segment.length > 0) {
    basePath = basePath + segment + '/';
  }
  var fullPath = origin + basePath + probePath;
  configFound = configExists(fullPath);
  if (configFound) {
    break;
  }
}

document.write("<base href='" + (configFound ? basePath : '/') + "' />");
```

Answer (score -1):

Frankly speaking, your case works fine for me!

I'm using Angular 5.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var base = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('index.aspx'))
    document.write('<base href="' + base + '" />');
</script>
```

Comment: Does this solution worked for you ? I am facing the problem. Can you please reply to my post as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757931/angular-5-dynamic-base-reference-is-causing-duplicate-loading-of-bundleschunk

Comment: Please avoid using document.write(): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Answer (score -15):

I just changed:

```html
  <base href="/">
```

to this:

```html
  <base href="/something.html/">
```

don't forget ending with /

Comment: how is this dynamic?