# In Angular, how can a prefix be added to all routes at startup or 'ignored'?

Tags: angular, angular-router, dreamfactory

**Background:** I would like all routes to be added a prefix by a service fired at startup.

The app is to access information about some events e.g. *AngularCodeWeek2015*, *NodeJSRetreat2017*, ... so the URLs should be of the format `http://www.eventsapp.com/<event_name>`

The `event_name` prefix is to act as a url parameter but we would like to have it as the first part of all paths rather than something like `http://www.eventsapp.com/?event=<event_name>`

(The Angular App is getting its data from [Dreamfactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com/) and the `event_name` will be used to retrieve the right API_KEY, which is different for each event. So at startup, Angular should retrieve the API_KEY using the `event_name` found in the URL and then get the relevant data for this event).

**Question:** After startup, the prefix is supposed to remain the first part of all paths. Yet, because the prefix is dynamically set, would there be a way to either add it to all paths at startup or make the angular router somehow 'ignore' it?

Comment: you mean there is some information in `url` and you just want that ? ignoring `prefixes` is Ok ? right ?

Comment: why use angular for this? use a classic <script> to do the href-setting action  and after that bootstrap angular with the static event_name prefix

Comment: Clarification: the prefix should be like a fake folder on the server. @UsmanRana: yes, the angular app should ignore the prefix. The prefix would just be read by the app at startup to get hold of the right API key, but then it should remain in the url through the whole app navigation.

Comment: @Phil: do you mean setting <base href="/<prefix>/">? Then what does it mean exactly to bootstrap angular with the static prefix?

Comment: @Phil: searching for solutions using your comment, I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/set-base-href-dynamically-angular-2-4 The scenario is very similar and the answers there probably answer my question (I still have to try it out)