# Angular routing - redirect url to component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular5, angular4-router

I have a problem with redirect my app in production mode. when I have url `http://server.com/projectname/dashboard`, server response IIS error page 404. I must open app using `http://server.com/projectname` and then click on link for example:

```
<a [routerLink]="'dashboard'">Dashboard</a>
```

In html i have `<base href="./">` and this is my router:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: '400', component: ErrorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '401', component: ErrorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '404', component: ErrorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ]
})
```

In development mode I have url `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` and i should redirect. Can it be problem when in developing is url localhost:4200/dashboard and in production is server.com/**appname**/dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. I must configuration fallback. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) is article about it.

I had to add web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now it works correctly and i can open arbitrary app url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the base href for your application. I would not recommend @Daniel's answer if you are using `angular-cli`, as there is a much easier approach.

With `angular-cli`, you can use: `ng build --prod --bh /appname/` and this will updated the production builds base href. This is a far better approach as you do not have to update this manually in the `index.html` when switching between environments.

[Set base href dynamically - Angular 2 / 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/set-base-href-dynamically-angular-2-4/41949470#41949470)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on your index.html when you deploy on production:

```
<base href="/appname/">
```