# Create static landing page but leave the rest of the app as Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Using example.com to represent my website, I would like users visiting example.com to reach a static website, but when they visit example.com/profile or example.com/dashboard, they will reach my Angular 12 app. I am using AWS EC2 to host my Angular app and my backend framework is Node/Nest, but it is just being used as an API (no routing, no possibility to use Angular Universal). I don't mind splitting up the landing page into a separate repo, but to the end user, the experience moving from example.com to example.com/home should be seamless. Any help is appreciated.

Note: This is a good suggestion [Using Static HTML landing page with Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570938/using-static-html-landing-page-with-angular-app?rq=1#comment86993978_48572113), however in my case, I cannot put my Angular app in a separate directory.

Comment: So you DON'T want a static landing page base on Angular and you DON'T want a separate directory. Why not just rename your angular HTML file to `index2.html` and then create a static index.html? You can then link to index2.html

Comment: I think you should ask this question in the Node/Nest forum, I don't think there's anything on the Angular side that could support this. The way I see it is that you will configure your Node/Nest server to serve your static site on the route `example.com`, and then serve the angular app on any sub route `example.com/*`