# nested routing in angular 6 not working

Tags: angular, nginx, angular6

I am trying all possible solutions but nothing seems to work.

Our project uses **nginx** to route to different modules. Mine is **supportui**.

```
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="./">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

now when the url is `/supportui` or `/supportui/route1` -> things work fine, since all the startup JS are downloaded from required path **supportui**
[image: when things work fine]

now when the url is `/supportui/route1/route2` -> the base becomes `supportui/route1` and all the required JS try to load from `supportui/route1`, which doesn't exist hence the app crashes.

[image: it crashes]

Comment: When deploying the app you need to change the base path, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically

Comment: I have tried all solutions given for that question, nothing helped, so posted this question. Am I missing something?

Comment: In your routing setup do you redirect more than once?

Comment: in my routing setup. I have child routes
so I redirect within them as well.

Comment: Redirecting more than once won't work. Do you want to paste your code?

Comment: forgot to mention, I am using pretty urls in my project