# Angular 4 Routes/RouterModule affecting path after domain

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

My Angular app is being hosted on a server that I am not in control of and that I can only access by navigating to this link.

```
externalServer.com/myAppName
```

Whenever I navigate to this link, I should see `/#/home` after `myAppName` but instead I see this.

```
externalServer.com/#/home
```

The issue is that `myAppName` is being removed from the path.  The URL that I want to see is this.

```
externalServer.com/myAppName/#/home
```

My question is this.  Is it possible that the Angular RouterModule or Routes component is causing this issue of the `myAppName` portion on the path being truncated off?  Or is the issue unrelated to Angular?

I am not familiar enough with Angular to know whether this is an issue with routes or something completely different, so I'm just trying to figure out where to put my energy.  I assume that if this is something that is fixable with Angular then the change would probably be needed in the app.module.ts file, so I will post that below.  Thanks for the help.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DesktopUiComponent } from './desktop-ui/desktop-ui.component';
import { MobileUiComponent } from './mobile-ui/mobile-ui.component';
import { RouterComponent } from './router/router.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: RouterComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DesktopUiComponent,
    MobileUiComponent,
    RouterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: When you did your build, did you pass `myAppName` as the base-href parameter? I am assuming you are using the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Comment: @R.Richards I was not aware of that parameter.  I just researched it a little bit though and it seems like the correct solution.  I have a small issue though and that is that this app will be deployed on multiple servers which will all have a different starting path.  Do you know if regular expressions can be used as the base-href value?

Comment: I don't know if that will work. I have not tried, nor have I seen it done.

Comment: Ok, well you have helped me a lot already.  Thank you!

Comment: Any time! Good luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find another post that answered my question.  The link is below.

[Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Set base href dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically)

Also, below is my updated app.module.ts file with the changes that allow the app to be run with any starting path.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DesktopUiComponent } from './desktop-ui/desktop-ui.component';
import { MobileUiComponent } from './mobile-ui/mobile-ui.component';
import { RouterComponent } from './router/router.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RouterComponent }
];

export function getBaseLocation() {
    let paths: string[] = location.pathname.split('/').splice(1, 1);
    let basePath: string = (paths && paths[0]) || '';
    return '/' + basePath;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DesktopUiComponent,
    MobileUiComponent,
    RouterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: getBaseLocation }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```