# base href in angular: change base-href in runtime?

Tags: angular, apache

I have 1 angular application with a base-href set to `/a/b/`.
So, in my `dist` folder, there is a html file with `<base href="/a/b/">`.
This way, the browser can resolve that a image link to `assets/images/logo.png` is in fact located on `domain.com/a/b/assets/images/logo.png`.

So my application runs on `domain.com/a/b/index.html`.

Problem:

Now I would also like to run the same application on `domain.com/a/b/c/index.html`. So besides the previous.
Also here `assets/images/logo.png` is located on `domain.com/a/b/c/assets/images/logo.png`. (watch the /c/ there).

I can get this to work, although, I really would like to build my application *once* and publish it *once*. And then deploy it twice (`/a/b/` and `/a/b/c/`).

So in fact my question is, can I configure this base-href after deploying it in the given folders on my apache server? Is there a run-time option? Can it infer it's base-path from the directory the files are in? 
Or, is there a command to change the value in index.html?

Comment: You can use the APP_BASE_HREF Injection Token as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501062/6513723

Answer (score -2):

you "could" deploy it to A) and then change the index.html on the fly with some Plugin in your build process and deploy it to B). But i would not advise that.
Better go the extra mile and have a second build.
The reason why i would do that is, that in most cases when you have two "identical" applications with different urls, than they are NOT identical. And may it be, that they only use two different backends.
At least i would like to have the possibility to use different environments-config-files for both applications.

I would define a second angular project in the angular json.
You could copy everything from the first one.
Only the name and the "baseHref" should be different.
Then all your changes will effect both applications, and the only thing you have to do is to build it two times.
Then you not much overhead and all the flexibility to change the environments-config (with fileReplacement in the angular-json).

Warm regards