# Changing the base href on angular navigate

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

While building my angular application using **ng build**, I have provided the **--base-href** flag for my application as **foo**. So the URL for my application looks like https://10.10.10.19:8080/foo. However I want to navigate to a page that has bar instead in the URL, i.e. https://10.10.10.19:8080/bar.

I tried router.navigateByUrl('/bar') but it creates a URL https://10.10.10.19:8080/foo/bar which is not what I am looking for.

Can someone help me with what is missing or going wrong here?

Comment: show me your code

Comment: Instead to be specific, show us your routing files. And also try changing the baseHref = "/" in index.html

Comment: setting up base for your app is explained in  an article that i have published , i hope  this will help you : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure after build but during development i use following code and its works for me..

```
this.router.navigate(['../bar'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: What is this.route here? Is it the ActivatedRoute instance you're talking about?

Comment: I am presently at the URL location https://10.10.10.19:8080/foo/a1 and want to navigate to https://10.10.10.19:8080/bar/b2.
With what you suggested I tried the same with `this.router.navigate(['../../bar/b1'], { relativeTo: this.route });`

But the same fails with invalid number of '../'. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have used `this.router.navigateByUrl('../../bar/b1')` and it seems to have desired effect

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want your base href to be set dynamically as you can not remove only base href (AFAIK).

Import base_HREF on main.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

and set your providers as below

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: '/' + (window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] || '')
    }
]
```

credit to this link : this link can be of use: [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Set base href dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `this.router.navigateByUrl('../../bar')` if you want navigate from base root

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved through dependency injection or through httpInterceptors.

I hope the below link will help your question.
http://www.projectcodify.com/angular-set-base-url-dynamically