# Angular 5 - Dynamic base reference is causing duplicate loading of bundles|chunks

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I am using Angular 5.2 version in the project. I am setting the base reference dynamically in the index.html to satisfy the different URL for different clients.

The app main page url looks like this :-

```
http://example.com/client1/app/login
http://example.com/client2/app/login
http://example.com/client3/app/login
```

client1, client2 etc are ***virtual directories*** in the IIS.

When i run the app in the browser, i can see from the inspect window that the duplicate chunks are getting loaded and causing the app page to slow down.

One thing i observed the web request url of the duplicate chunks. let's say script.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.bundles.css.

First web request:- 
**https://example.com/client1/scripts.7186135389ca4b63fab4.bundle.js**

Second web request (duplicated):-**https://example.com/scripts.7186135389ca4b63fab4.bundle.js**

The second web-request is not desired. And i am not able to gauge how it is coming up.

[image]

Index.html is looking this like in my project :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Web</title>
        <link href="/assets/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <base id="baseHref" href="/">
        <script>
            (function () {
                if (window.location.hostname !== 'localhost') document.getElementById('baseHref').href = "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/";
            })();
        </script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please suggest, how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Why do not you use angular's routing instead ?

Comment: Please suggest how can i use the angular routing to accomplish this client specific thing.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact they're virtual directories.

Comment: And the issue is gone when you remove base href manipulation ??

Comment: Is that complete index.html?? I dont see any angular scripts loading tags here.

Comment: yes, this is complete index.html file content. ng build --prod generates the remaining files and add to the index.html during the build step.

Comment: I did not tried yet by removing the base href manipulation code. Let me try that.

Comment: ng build --prod generates the remaining file content by adding the script references during the ng build step.

Comment: This is command i am using. ng build --prod -e=dev --base-href=/Client1

Comment: Thats the point. So what you need to investigate is resulting index.html not the source one.

Comment: What I am suspecting is that angular srcipts are getting loaded before baseurl changes and due to detect of that change app tries to reload itself. But that is just blind guess - did you check wha happens if you remove that ?

Comment: Also, since you are already building app with base href, cant you build it separately for every client?

Comment: I can't build the code separately for every client. Your guess could be right. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies during the ng build arguments.

Earlier it was

```
ng build --prod -e=dev --base-href=/Client1
```

After i added the ending / to the ng build statement, it worked fine.

```
ng build --prod -e=dev --base-href=/Client1/
```

The duplicate angular chunks gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng build --base-href /myUrl/`.

Or add `"baseHref" : "MY_APP_BASE_HREF_2"` in your `angular.json`.

Related post with more info: [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Set base href dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

> Add this to head section in index.html

```
<base href="/">
 <script>
 (function() {
  window['_app_base'] = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
 })();
</script>
```

> Then in the app.module.ts file, add { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 
>   window['_app_base'] || '/' } to the list of providers, like so:

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent, routing, appRoutingProviders, environment } from './';
 if (environment.production) {
 enableProdMode();
}

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule,
   routing],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   providers: [
   appRoutingProviders,
   { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/' },
 ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you tried this approach with Virtual Directory setup.

Comment: This doesn't work on angular universal as ssr

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the HTML attribute, use [the APP_BASE_HREF provider](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF). You can use a dynamic factory to have a value that changes over time.

Comment: In my case, i have Virtual Directory for each client pointing to same codebase in IIS. Will this change work in my scenario ?

Comment: I never played around with Virtual directories and IIS, so can't say for sure. Although, if that does what I think it does, it should be fine. I guess it needs trying (simply try with constant values `Client1`, `Client2` and no html baseref and see if it works as you expect).

Comment: I tried the APP_Base_HREF approach. But i still have to keep the   <base id="baseHref" href="/"> in the index.html.

Comment: If i remove the <base> tag from index.html , it does not work. The app gives the error.

Comment: @Karan can you provide how you solved? I'm trying leaving the index.html as angular/cli creates, and putting {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'my-path' } in the App.module.ts, but it's ignored...

Comment: ng build --prod -e=dev --base-href=/Client1/. 

I just added the last slash after /Client1

Comment: @Qortex Can you please share a rough draft of how would that factory look like?

Isn't the factory just called once on app load?
    `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF,  
useFactory: myFactory}`

How can myFactory provide different values over time?