# Angular How to set Dynamically(runtime) --deploy-url?

Tags: angular

I am able to set base-href dynamically as below.

**index.html**

```
<script>
  window['base-href'] = window.location.pathname;
</script>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [ 
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['base-href'] },
    ],
```

this worked well for routing.

**Its not working for assets loading**

How can i set for assets ? 
--deploy-url is works at compile time but how can i do it at runtime ?

mentioned link is for routing not for assets (images etc) which are loading from SCSS files.

**All my http calls happening properly**

Example : *`https://domain/<env>/<contexname>/<restcall_URI>`*

**images loading from SCSS not happening**

Exmaple: 
Url generated for fetching images :*`https://domain/assets/img/xyz.jpg`*

Desired URL : *`https://domain/<env>/<contexname>/assets/img/xyz.jpg`*

how to tell angular to fetch images with Desired URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Set base href dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically)

Comment: @Ahmed, mentioned link is for routing not for assets (images etc) which are loading from SCSS files.  All my http calls happening properly 
Example : https://domain/<env>/<contexname>/<restcall_URI>

images loading from SCSS not happening
Exmaple: 
Url generated for fetching images :https://domain/assets/img/xyz.jpg 

Desired URL : https://domain/<env>/<contexname>/assets/img/xyz.jpg 

how to tell angular to fetch images with Desired URL

Comment: In angular `scss` image path is related to the `scss` file itself, for example, you have `home.component.scss` living at `src/app/` directory and you want to load an image from `src/assets/images` your path will be `url('../assets/images/myimage.png')` is it makes sense now?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking to serve Angular files from CDN. Ended up adding this code to main.ts:

```
declare let __webpack_public_path__: any;
__webpack_public_path__ = window['cdnUrl'];
```

In your index.html you could set `cdnUrl` dynamically

```
window.cdnUrl = 'https://...';
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case we needed same dist file set to work with and without url path prefix. Solution was to use relative deploy-url and dynamically changed  html tag

```
--deploy-url ../static/
```

or you may need

```
--deploy-url ./static/
```

and

```
  <base href="/some-path/">
```

or

```
  <base href="/">
```