# Set "baseHref" based on external config file

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to setup `baseHref` for my angular app dynamically. Additionally the final `baseHref` is stored in `config.json` in different location so I have to make a http request for that, but how Can I do that in module?

Now, my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [        
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/path/'
    },
  ...
})
```

How can I simply update `useValue` field with every page refresh and additionally get this value from http request.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically/41949470

Comment: Nope, I can't use 'window' in app.module.ts because it's angular-universal and this solution don't include external `baseHref` from another config file.

Comment: Maybe use the `APP_INITIALIZER` token to retrieve the config file first, and then use the value to provide `APP_BASE_HREF` ?

Comment: @David good idea, now I can get expected value using `APP_INITIALIZER` and some additional service,  but how can I pass this variable to `useValue` field of `APP_BASE_HREF`?

Comment: Maybe set a global variable with the wanted value when providing the `APP_INITIALIZER_TOKEN`, then use that value with `useValue` when providing `APP_BASE_HREF `( or try`useFactory` if `useValue` does not work)