# NGINX Run multiple application on same port with different route path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have two applications, app1 is developed in reactJS and app2 in angularJS sharing same login session,

```
 - Application 1
http://application-1:1234/
 - APplication 2
http://application-2:2345/
```

My needs is to have a seemless navigation between both apps, as they share the same login credentials.

I have created NGINX reverse proxy configuration,

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name http://global-ip:8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application-1:1234;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
    location /application-2 {
        proxy_pass http://application-2:2345;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

}
```

As the above configuration is working for only, First default root path. The other /application-2 is not able to redirect to specified path.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Praveen T

Comment: Try add one more slash (/) to the application2 block like this `location /application-2/ {...}`

Comment: Hi Ted, Thanks for the reply I tried the suggestion but there it gives 404 error

Comment: Can you explain what specifically not works?

Comment: As per the above configuration of nginx default file working for only, First default root path (I.e. location /). The other /application-2 is not able to redirect to specified link of application-2.

Comment: Seem like you need to add one more slash in here, change `proxy_pass http://application-2:2345;` to `proxy_pass http://application-2:2345/;` Respone if it works bro.

Comment: @Ted Tried this combination as well it still not coming

Comment: But is it 404 error or other came ? I tried that config with my simple application but it got same problems. Even i added some slashes but it just solved404 problem then other issues came. I checked network of Chrome developers tool then there ware a lot of problems about URI. I think this is not a good practise of config when i read these questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/650117/serving-multiple-proxy-endpoints-under-location-in-nginx https://serverfault.com/questions/706694/use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-servers

Comment: Ya it is giving blank page, not able to load the page itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick hack, try either

```
location /application-2/ {
    proxy_pass http://application-2:2345/;
    ...
}
```

or

```
location /application-2/ {
    rewrite ^/application-2(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://application-2:2345;
    ...
}
```

but you'd better build you angular app according to your URI prefix, see instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-4-5-set-base-href-dynamically). Then your original config should work as expected.

Comment: Hey Ivan, Thanks a lot man, the above method didn't worked but the link which you have provided to change the URI prefix in the angular app have worked.

Comment: <base href="/" id="baseHref">
<script>
  (function() {
    document.getElementById('baseHref').href = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/";
  })();
</script>

Comment: No Ivan, that workaround didn't got succeeded, I tried before as well :)

Comment: @praveen2609 Well, anyway setting correct `base href` is the best approach for this case.

Comment: Yes, your right Ivan setting correct base href is the best approach. It was a great help as i was struggling to find the solution but the way you gave the direction have helped me. Thanks again for your valuable input and stay safe and stay at home.

Comment: @praveen2609 So you still keep original nginx config and just change base href ?

Comment: Yes Ted, Keeping the configuration same and changed the base href url as per the above comment.