# Speculative parsing cases problem with dynamic HTML base tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-parser

Consider a web page where the HTML `base` tag is generated dynamically (based on the current environment settings):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        // envconfig.js sets value to window.ENV.htmlBaseUrl
        <script src="envconfig.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<base href="' + window.ENV.htmlBaseUrl + '"/>');
        </script>

        <link href="some-impatient-styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

Here comes the issue. In the past, the `document.write` script would simply block HTML parser until it is finished, i.e. until the `base` tag is properly generated. However modern browsers do use speculative parsing (alson known as lookahead parsers) that find and try to load `some-impatient-styles.css` even before the `base` tag is generated. Therefore browser (tested in Chrome, but other browsers do the same) sends request to wrong URL and even obtains a wrong CSS file (due to some URL rewrite magic on the server side). Sure, browser also makes additional request later when `base` tag comes into play and gets a new (correct) css file. Still I want to get rid of the previous bad request.

Is there any chance to disable speculative parsing - ideally only until this very specific `document.write` is finished?

The only idea I have got so far is to generate links to CSS files dynamically via JS as well. But I would prefer not to go this dirty road (having a single `document.write` in the index file is "ugh" enough). Plus, that would break my current gulp build setup.

I cannot have the server insert the tag since IIS does not allow that if static/dynamic compression is turned on. I really want to avoid generating CSS links and also the base tag is primarily used for client side navigation (it is an AngularJS SPA) so I cannot avoid the tag.

Comment: Is there any valid case to be made for using `document.write` in 2020 at all? This function has been on the "this is really bad, don't use it"-list literally forever.

Comment: Writing the base tag sounds like a task to do on the server ..?

Comment: there is no 'dirty road' here - in this case only your subjective perception. Loading necessary styles dynamically is completely OK. But as mentioned @Teemu - it is best to use server in this case.

Comment: Long story short, I cannot have the tag inserted by server (probably I should have stated this in the question). @Tomalak, yeah, I would like to avoid `document.write` too but I don't think that it is possible under the given circumstances, is it?

Comment: "I can't do it on the server side" is a bad excuse. This problem should not exist at all, and that it does is a sign of bad design. I get it, you're trying to run the same page in DEV and PROD and that's the thing you did to make it work, but really, do it differently. Everybody else does it differently too. It's a bad idea and fixing this approach is not worth it.

Comment: @Tomalak, no, that is not the case. PROD version is being built by gulp - no issue there. Issue is with multiple DEV environments. It is easier to state the status quo rather than explain all what is behind the given circumstances. Therefore I would appreciate a constructive suggestion (within the boundaries of the given circumstances) instead of just stating that the chosen approach is bad. The same as with your first comment, since it was Teemu who suggested server side injection. You only stated the obvious. Thx for any help.

Comment: Sometimes "this is a bad idea, don't do it" is help. This is one of those times.

Comment: @Tomalak, in which case I would be happy to hear an alternative solution (respecting the given boundaries). That brings us to the original question about avoiding speculative parsing. Is that even possible? If so, how?

Comment: If *"respecting given boundaries"* means *"using `document.write`"*, then I can't help you. The solution is to not use `document.write`. In a wider sense, the solution is to adopt a file structure that does not require `<base href="">` to work.

Comment: @Tomalak, using HTML `base` tag is required by Angular JS, quoting the docs [AngularJS requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links). Using `document.write` it not a boundary, it is an (unfortunate) implication of the boundaries (please see the original question to understand the circumstances). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular. But I found [a thread about this very problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949470/18771), particularly the top voted answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501062/18771) sound promising to me.

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you for the hint. Unfortunately that topis is about Angular, not Angular JS (Angular is a successor to Angular JS but there is a huge difference between those two).

Comment: The one stable way to get different values into the `<base hre="">` is to let the server do it. Since you're using IIS, maybe trying [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is worth consideration. It does not only rewrites on incoming requests, it also has a module that can [do text replacements on outbound HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: @Tomalak I do use URL Rewrite, however text replacement on outbound HTML is messed up when used together with compression - as stated in the question. That is why I cannot use it. I would really love to hear suggestion how to turn of the speculative parsing as I think I have already explored the other options.

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to do that. I don't think you have not explored all the other options - things like finding out why URL Rewrite and Compression seem to have issues when used together, or using URL Rewrite to serve different CSS files from the same fixed endpoint based on some condition, or restructuring your dev/testing environment). But you're set on wagging the dog, and who am I to stop you, really. All I can do is wish you good luck.

Comment: @Tomalak I do not think I can solve IIS issues (unless I apply for a job in MS). Plus you misunderstood, it is not the combination of URL Rewrite and Compression but combination of HTML injection and Compression that is not working properly on IIS (never mind). Also I do already use URL Rewrite and my environment is structured accordingly. Thank you for wishing me good luck, however on this forum I would rather get an answer to my original question - how to avoid speculative parsing? Thank you in advance.