# Why does angular router url doesn't have the same value as window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

Was working on my website and had to do some request to the api while instantiating a `root` services.

I wanted to get some data based on the url, so I did the following

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
     this.init() 
  }

  init() {
    console.log('url', this._router.url, window.location.href)
    // this._router.url : `/`
    // window.location.href : `http://localhost:4201/my/url`
    // Here I'll make some get request with the url
  }
}
```

But I see the the router doesn't have the correct value yet, or at least, not all the time.

Funnily, sometime it does work.

What should I do to be able to get the location without using the `window` object?

Answer (score 3):

window.location.href defines DOM location, while router.url is based on basehref.
Check basehref and RouterModule.forRoot([])

Comment: If I cannot change the baseRef, then it kind of not doable to work with the `router.url`, is it correct ?

Comment: Have you included RouterModule.forRoot([]) in app.module.ts imports?

Comment: Yes I did. 
About "I cannot change the baseRef" I do mean that my project doesn't allow it because it would breaks other logics inside my app. This one is pretty well explaining my problem and also kind of resolving it, together with your answer. I'll update once I find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-set-base-href-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Basically you use Angular Router to route between pages inside your application, and for every external route you should use window.location/href(html).

As answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72514835/12677894

window.location.href defines DOM location, while router.url is based on basehref *

Comment: I did read somewhere (sry, do not find the link) that it wasn't safe to use global variable like `window.location.href` since angular could be imported somewhere else in an app that wasn't inside some browser, which will then create an error trying to read this variable.

It's seems like you answer may create such error and it was the reason why I've described in my question that I didn't wanted to use such variable