# Angular Routing Changing the Root of the original request URL base

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular application using routing.

It's default page (index.html) is located /somefolder/index.html

I need the rest of the application to live /someotherfolder/ ... all scripts and resources

I can get this to work with deploy-url, modifying the base ref etc.

so navigation to

http://someip/somefolder/

works , but angular changes that url to

http://someip/someotherfolder/#/route where route is one of my routes.

Is there a way to keep the original base ? ie

http://someip/somefolder/#/route

Everthing I've tried has not suceeded. Also yes they HAVE to live in different areas of the server due to limitations beyond the scope of this question. Many thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

Adding more detail.
When navigating to
https://IP/xyz/fva/index.html
I end up here ( where everything but index.html lives.
https://IP/html/FvaConfig/#../../xya/fva/stage
Also there is a child route so you can have  https://IP/html/FvaConfig/#../../xya/fva/stage/(child:status)
Which works , until you try to refresh ( this is using hash )  Then it attempts to use
https://IP/html/FavfConfig/ which is not the location of index.html
Now if I do not use hash
https://IP/xyz/fva/stage
Does get me where I want
Refresh works as well.
But ....when I hit a child route
https://IP/xya/fva/stage/(child:status)
I get where I want , but refresh doesn't work.
I have enableTracing on
Cannot match any routes. 'xya/fva/stage'
but I do have that route
{
path: 'xyz/fva/stage',
pathMatch: 'full',
redirectTo: 'stage',
},
I am at a loss

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41674411/7906693) answer, you can provide `APP_BASE_HREF` in your app module to change the base URL used by the router.

In your case, the URL isn't dynamic, so if you have an environment file, you can set the base URL there and provide it like this:

```
// Inside @NgModule in AppModule...
providers: [
  // Other providers...
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: environment.appBaseUrl
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I was using APP_BASE_HREF, and I did simplify the question a bit. There are child routes involved. I'll get something like 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cws/AVF/stage''. But already have a route for that {
    path: 'cws/AVF/stage',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'stage',
  },  Seems like i'm close , but the addition of the child routes adds another layer on the fly. Now I did try using the location to base the APP_BASE_HREF on , and debugged it working. But still can't find the route.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Did you get it to work? If I understood your edit correctly, it seems that Angular isn't using the provided base URL and is using the one where the default page is located instead. Perhaps it is being overwritten somewhere else? Also, you said that you got it working when debugging, but it still couldn't find the route, so what worked?

Comment: So what worked was catching location in app initializer and redirecting if the url was undesired. Was a hack , but spent waaay too much time on this . I love angular, except the router. It's always been a source of problems.