# SETUP dynamic base href in angular and scripts also load from dynamic href

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I need to deploy my angular app in Node server . I need to deploy that build in different URL like

> [www.xyz.com/sandbox/xyz/portal?n=1](http://www.xyz.com/sandbox/xyz/portal?n=1)
>
> [www.xyz.com/live/xyz/portal?n=1](http://www.xyz.com/live/xyz/portal?n=1)

and in node JS

```
app.get("sandbox/xyz/portal/*",express.static(__dirname+'/portal'))//portal is my angular build
```

I can achive this by adding

> ng build --base-href "/sandbox/xyz/portal"

and its work fine , but I want to add dynamic for URL 1 and 2 . if I try to use [APP_BASE_HREF](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) Then my scripts try to load from

> [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)

instead

> [www.xyz.com/sandbox/xyz/portal](http://www.xyz.com/sandbox/xyz/portal)

Comment: are you using nginx on your server? with nginx you can achive this by adding some rules for this routes to redirect

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your question and you should look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112891/angular-2-set-base-href-dynamically