# How to create Angular2 npm package with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I would like create a npm package for a project. I used angular-cli to create my components I would like package.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "mapRoot": "./",
      "module": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
      ]
   } 
}
```

I can generate `*.d.ts` with `ng build`

And then, with `npm link` I can test my package into other project, but my module which contains my components is not found.. :/

Have you some ideas ? :)

Comment: Your question is not really clear as to what your issue is - are you saying that you build out your app and it doesn't work? Because that could be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558656/angular-clis-ng-build-doesnt-produce-a-working-project

Comment: I can not generate my project in order to use it in another project as a dependency with npm

Comment: Currently you're not able to do it via CLI. Follow this thread, you can find a lot of interesting stuff here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692#issuecomment-273989471

Comment: There is a post and sample code [here](https://www.usefuldev.com/blog/post/publishing-a-library-from-an-angular-cli-project) showing how to isolate a module in an Angular-cli project and publish it as an npm package which might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I think this [documentation](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) will help you. I have successfully created npm package using yoman from my angular2 component.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's extremely helpful!