# Angular CLI, ng build command doesnt compile properly

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Im using the latest version of angular-cli.
If I understood rightly, I can use ng build to obtain a compiled project in a js representation. In a /dist folder, according to documentation by default.

Im new with JS, so I simply cant understand how can I launch the project...

Command works fine, and I can find a bunch of files in a folder, but how can I launch a project as expected (like it was in a dev mode with ts-files)? I mean simply launching index.html just shows me a "Loading.." text, but application doesnt launch how it was expected.

Help please.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you get the app to run from a file, with messing base href etc, some things might not work (maybe AJAX, etc).

The `dist` folder is meant to be used with a server.

If you want to just browse the app, regardless of the files, you can run `ng serve`, which will serve the app in-memory (for speed) at http://localhost:4200, and will sit and watch for changes, and update the page when you make them.

When you are done developing, you run `ng build`, and take the contents of the dist folder to your server.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a webserver. Just copy the contents of the /dist folder to a webserver root and you're ready to go.

What is your goal? Ng build is meant to create a distributable version of your app, ng serve is meant for local development.

Comment: Just found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558656/angular-clis-ng-build-doesnt-produce-a-working-project. I needed to add a dot here in index.html <base href="./">. Thanks for attention, Mike!

Comment: Mike, sorry its out of topic, but maybe u can help.. So Im going to using DigitalOcean (with dedicated Ubuntu) to launch this app remotely. What am I going to do is to open this essential index.html through node.js which I had already installed. It should works, but maybe there is a more common and better solution?

Comment: Maybe it is better to start a new question with some more specifics about what you're teying to achieve?

Comment: @Michael thanks for the comment. your `dot` saved my day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command

```
ng build -prod
```

Also set in the `environments/environment.ts` file, the property `"production":true`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

That will create a `dist` folder, ready to deploy

Answer (score 0):

There is new angular-cli tool, install that

Perform these one by one...

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I completely removed the node_modules directory (`rm -rf node_modules dist`),
Generate a new project and compare files like your package.json, angular-cli.json  by `ng new temp`
Compare & Changed the package.json to match the "dependencies" and "devDependencies".
Fixed the angular-cli.json file for changes in the environment configs.

run `ng serve` after the `npm install`