# Angular App routerlinks are working fine in dev but not in production?

Tags: angular, typescript

When ever I run `npm start` command my angular works fine as expected.

But when I tried to build it in *"prod"* mode my application is doing nothing.
It just displays static page.

*All navigation links are stopped working*

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "srm-roster",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json --port 5555",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    -- so on --
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    -- so on --
  }
}
```

This is how my **app-routing.module.ts** looks like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }, {
    path: 'rostertable',
    component: RostertableComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo : 'dashboard'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error logs in the console

Comment: but I did one change in the index.html file `<base href="./">` I added '.' dot to the href

Comment: any specific reason behind changes in index.html file?

Comment: It was displaying the blank page before I did that change. [by referring to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558656/angular-cli-ng-build-doesnt-produce-a-working-project)

Comment: I'm getting warning :  `Unhandled Navigation Error: 
t.warn @ main.1f12da3a33c5f2a48b78.js:1`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.

I just moved my `dist/project_name` folder inside Xampp/htdocs and it started working.

I found answer to my question in this [link](https://angular.io/guide/router)